# How does downloadable content work in a react-native app for iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, app-store

I'm making a simple puzzle game using react-native. I intend to offer it for free while providing paid Downloadable Content (DLC) that adds more puzzles. Puzzles are described using JSON, and the base game will bundle a .json file with the free content.

How does DLC work? I know this is a very broad question. If you can point me to a primer that explains the basic ecosystem, without requiring expertise in C# or Swift, that is a good start. (I'm only targeting iOS right now.)

Here are some examples of the kind of information I'm looking for:

- is a DLC pack technically a separate app that I must create & publish through the App Store?
- what is actually downloaded to the device when a user purchases DLC?
- is the base app somehow notified that DLC has been downloaded?
- does DLC just add files to the base app bundle, or does it exist as a separate bundle?
- how can I tell, from within the app, whether a piece of DLC has been downloaded?
- do I need to maintain records indicating which users have paid for DLC, or does the App Store handle that through the user's AppleID?

I am aware that *one* strategy is to bundle all free and paid content with the base app, "unlocking" paid content if and when the user buys. I think that's fine, but I don't know what "unlocking" could look like at the implementation level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- is a DLC pack technically a separate app that I must create & publish
  through the App Store?

No. It's called an In App Purchase (IAP) and you must create and publish it thru AppStore Connect (aka iTunes Connect).

- what is actually downloaded to the device when
  a user purchases DLC?

A receipt for purchase and optionally more content

- is the base app somehow notified that DLC has
  been downloaded?

Yes.

All other questions could be answered by reading the In App Purchase Programming guide (still more or less valid: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html)